# Rollback a Executed Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback

I have executed a wrong query. I need to get it back

Here is the Query;

```
UPDATE INLOCATE.Location
SET IsActive = 0
WHERE LocationId < 558
```

How can I get it back ?

I am using MS SQL Server!

Comment: don't cry over spilt milk :D once gone, gone forever

Comment: Do you have a log?

Comment: IF u Have yesterday Backup of DB.from That DB u can get most of Data Back

Comment: Don't worry. We've all done it. Go buy your IT guys/DBA's some cakes (for mistakes) and get them to restore yesterdays backup.

Comment: If you don't execute this in a transaction you must resort to either manually updating the affected rows back by figuring out what value to restore, or you must restore the whole database from backup. There's no undo mechanism in SQL Server, other than executing in a transaction and rolling it back instead of committing it.

Comment: Note that you can restore your backup to a different database name so that you don't mess with other tables in your production database, and then grab the data from that table from the restored database and update them into the production database.